# Optimize Bitmap Heap Scan

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I am trying to understand why my query takes a really long time even though I have the required columns indexed:

```
SELECT entity_id,
       id,
       report_date
FROM own_inst_detail
WHERE ( own_inst_detail.id = 'P7M7WC-S' )
  AND ( own_inst_detail.report_date >= '2017-02-01T17:29:49.661Z' )
  AND ( own_inst_detail.report_date <= '2018-08-01T17:29:49.663Z' )
```

The cached result of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is as follows:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on own_inst_detail (cost=20.18..2353.55 rows=597 width=22) (actual time=1.471..6.955 rows=4227 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((id = 'P7M7WC-S'::bpchar) AND (report_date >= '2017-06-01'::date) AND (report_date <= '2018-08-01'::date))
  Heap Blocks: exact=4182
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on own_inst_detail  (cost=0.00..20.03 rows=597 width=0) (actual time=0.901..0.901 rows=4227 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((id = 'P7M7WC-S'::bpchar) AND (report_date >= '2017-06-01'::date) AND (report_date <= '2018-08-01'::date))
Planning time: 0.123 ms
Execution time: 7.801 ms
```

This part of the query takes 4 out of 5 total seconds that my full query takes.

I have combined index for **id** and **report_date**. I also have two standalone indexes for those columns.

I've tried playing around with setting high **work_mem** as well as lowering the **random_page_cost**  but nothing really helps.

Any additional suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I found similar question [How to index WHERE (start_date >= '2013-12-15')](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62269/how-to-index-where-start-date-2013-12-15) which recommends adding a B-Tree index, but I already do have index for **report_date**.

Create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.own_inst_detail (
    entity_id character(8) NOT NULL,
    id character(8) NOT NULL,
    report_date date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(report_date)
);
```

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX indx_own_inst_detail_report_date_desc ON own_inst_detail (report_date DESC NULLS LAST)

CREATE INDEX indx_own_inst_detail_id_report_date_desc ON own_inst_detail (id, report_date DESC NULLS LAST)
```

Comment: Please always provide Postgres version, table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and relevant index definitions for performance optimization. And all other relevant details. Consider instructions in the [tag:postgresql-performance] tag info.

Comment: Your data types are bothersome ... I see `date`in the query plan but you use `timestamp` literals in the query. And `bpchar` seems like a misunderstanding. Neither may be the root of the perf problem, but both may cause problems.

Comment: Updated the question with additional info

Comment: What does the uncached plan results look like?  Also, please include `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Better yet, turn on track_io_timing first as well.

Comment: You can determine your Postgres version with `SELECT version()` btw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Data types

The data type `character(n)` is almost always the wrong choice. It's a "legacy" type I wouldn't use any more. It exhibits surprising behavior and does nothing `text` / `varchar` / `varchar(n)` couldn't do better.

- [Any downsides of using data type “text” for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/939860)

And you are mixing type `date` in the table with `timestamp` literals in the query. While this *works*, you should at least provide explicit type declaration to defend against surprising results. Better yet, provide actual *dates* in the query or cast input explicitly. Like

```
report_date >= timestamp '2017-02-01T17:29:49.661Z'
```

Or:

```
report_date >= date '2017-02-02'
```

The manual about [constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) and [type casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS).

#### Index

Your index `indx_own_inst_detail_id_report_date_desc` on `(id, report_date DESC NULLS LAST)` **looks good for the query**, and the query plan you provided makes good use of it. `Execution time: 7.801 ms` does not seem too bad either.

If your "uncached" query takes 4 seconds, then you may have to work on your hardware or server configuration or both. **Slow storage** and not enough **RAM for cache**? More `work_mem` is not the cure for this, may even make it worse by taking away RAM from cache memory. Related:

- [Increasing work_mem and shared_buffers on Postgres 9.2 significantly slows down queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27893/increasing-work-mem-and-shared-buffers-on-postgres-9-2-significantly-slows-down/33622)

If you have enough RAM and proper [memory settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html) this might burn down to an issue of **cold cache**: Only the first invocation is slow (or the first few invocations). If that's a problem, consider [`pg_prewarm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgprewarm.html). See:

- [PostgreSQL: Force data into memory](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/postgresql-force-data-into-memory/116536#116536)

**If** your table is vacuumed enough (or mostly read-only) you may profit from **[index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)** if you append the one additional column `entity_id` in your `SELECT` list to the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON own_inst_detail (id, report_date DESC NULLS LAST, entity_id)
```

That might be particularly useful in your situation since Postgres only accesses the index in this case and does not need to visit the table at all. (**Eliminating the `Bitmap Heap Scan` completely.**) May help with your disk / cold cache bottleneck.

Related:

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/can-postgres-use-an-index-only-scan-for-this-query-with-joined-tables)

Comment: I need more fields from that table, I just simplified the query for you to easily understand, so index-only scan won't work in this case

Comment: Also our current machine that runs the process has 8 gigs of RAM and 2 CPUs, do you think increasing that could make a difference?

Comment: @inside: Hard to say. Depends on the complete picture. What you describe sounds like "cold cache". I added some more above.

Comment: thanks a lot @erwin I'll play around with pre-warm, do you think it's feasible to prewarm the table if it has 40 million records?

Comment: @inside: Depends, depends. If you have enough cache. You may be able to only fetch relevant parts of the table into cache.